# Has Mac Lane's article "When can a graph be mapped on a torus?" been published anywhere?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I came across the following abstract of an article: Mac Lane, S., [When can a graph be mapped on a torus?](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1936-06376-7), Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 42(9), 629 (1936). Abstract #341. [MR1563375](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1563375), [JFM 62.0694.07](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:62.0694.07).

**Q.** Does anyone know whether the full paper has been published, or is otherwise available to read anywhere?

I noticed that a related paper by Mac Lane (also mentioned in the above abstract) was published a year later: Mac Lane, S., [A combinatorial condition for planar graphs](https://eudml.org/doc/212919), Fundam. Math., Warszawa, 28(1), 22–32 (1937). [Zbl 0015.37501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0015.37501), [JFM 63.0548.01](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:63.0548.01).

However, the paper that I'm looking for does not seem to have appeared anywhere, as far as I can tell from my searches…

Comment: In my searches, I located the following (recent) related work: _Bruhn, Henning; Diestel, Reinhard_, [**MacLane's theorem for arbitrary surfaces**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jctb.2008.03.005), J. Comb. Theory, Ser. B 99, No. 2, 275–286 (2009). [MR2482947](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2482947), [Zbl 1180.05036](https://zbmath.org/1180.05036). Extended version: [**Embedding graphs in surfaces: MacLane's theorem for higher genus**](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/papers/MLextended.pdf).